# Using the linux filters program to change buffer text?

Tags: linux, vim

I am trying to figure out how to perhaps issue a command in gvim on Debian stable to convert buffer text into say text filtered into jive, chef as used by the filters program. Have tried using :r and a few various other tips found but none seem to really work out well. I am probably missing something which upon revelation will be easy. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It be as simple as

```
:[range]!jive
```

Fo' de current line, dig dis:

```
:.!jive
```

Fo' de visual selecshun:

```
:'<,'>!jive
```

Fo' de whole document, dig dis:

```
:%!jive
```

Wow, this filter is horrible! Quick: `$ sudo port uninstall jive`

Answer (score 1):

The various filter commands are documented in section 4.1 of the vim documentation, "Filter commands", accesible via `:h filter`.

Comment: Like I said, something simple. Didn't even think of :h filter and should have. Thank you for replying though.

Comment: In similar vein, been reading documentation on vim tips wiki regarding key maps. One can use :%! par 72 to reformat a buffer to 72 columns of text using par. Thought I would quickly and easily assign a key map to execute this command. What I have follows.                                                             " Shift F2 to reformat buffer with Par
cmap <buffer><Shift>-<F2> par 72<CR>                                 However, this does not seem to function to execute the command. Shift+F2 is not otherwise mapped, according to :map<CR>. Am probably forgetting a dot somewhere?

Comment: Got it to work. Adjusted the key mapping to  map <silent><buffer> <F2> :%! par 72<CR> .